# existence of a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} $ be a sequence such that $\liminf |a_n| = 0$.

Prove that there is a subsequence $
(a_{n_{k}})_{k=1}^{\infty} $ of $(a_n)$ such that
$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n_{k}}$  converges.

By theorem there exists a subsequence of $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} $ that is monotonic (increasing i believe) to $\liminf a_n = 0$ denote it $(a_{n_{k}})_{k=1}^{\infty} $ we know that $\lim(a_{n_{k}})_{k=1}^{\infty} = 0 $ since $\liminf |a_n| = 0$.

Hence by the definition $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n_{k}}$  converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\liminf_n |a_n| = 0$, then for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ you can find an index $n_k$ such that $|a_{n_k}| \leq 2^{-k}$. Moreover, you can choose the $n_k$ such that $n_{k+1} > n_k$ for every $k$.

Comment: True, but just make sure the $n_k$ are strictly increasing.

Comment: Yes, sure. Thank you for your remark.

Comment: Why do you need strictly increasing?  also why that sequence?

Comment: To have a subsequence, you need increasing indexes, i.e. $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$. You can choose $n_k$ such that $|a_{n_k}| \leq c_k$ with $\sum_k c_k$ convergent. The choice $c_k = 2^{-k}$ is just one possible choice.